# Why my way of defining Coercion in this example is wrong, and what is the correct way?

Tags: coq

My Coq code is as follows:

```
    Inductive A (X: Type) :=
      n1 : nat -> X -> (A X)
    .

    Arguments n1 {X} _ _. 

    Inductive B :=
      m1 : (A nat) -> B |
      m2 : B -> B -> B
    .

    Coercion m1 : A >-> B.

    Check m2 (m1 (n1 1 2)) (m1 (n1 2 2)). (* 1st Check *)
    Check m2 (n1 1 2) (n1 2 2). (* 2nd Check *)
```

I defined types A and B (A is a polymorphic type). When writing down an expression of B connected by operator 'm2' (like the '1st Check'), I wish to omit the constructor 'm1' (like the '2nd Check'), so I defined a coercion as above. However only the `1st Check' works, the '2nd Check' does not work.

What is the correct way of using coercion here? And why my definition is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is any convenient way of getting what you want with the current coercion engine.  When you enter `m1` as a coercion, Coq says that it does not respect the uniform inheritance condition.  This happens when you declare a coercion between type families that fixes some of the parameters; here, you fixed `X` to be `nat`.  When this condition is broken, Coq's typechecker refuses to apply the coercion.

One partial solution is to introduce an intermediate type:

```
Inductive A (X: Type) :=
      n1 : nat -> X -> (A X)
    .

    Arguments n1 {X} _ _.

Definition Anat := A nat.
Identity Coercion Anat_of_A : Anat >-> A.

Inductive B :=
  m1 : Anat -> B |
  m2 : B -> B -> B
.

Coercion m1 : Anat >-> B.

Check m2 (m1 (n1 1 2)) (m1 (n1 2 2)). (* 1st Check *)
Check m2 (n1 1 2 : Anat) (n1 2 2 : Anat). (* 2nd Check *)
```

The problem is that the `n1` still produces something of type `A` at the end, instead of `Anat`.  Therefore, you need the explicit cast to convince Coq to trigger the coercion.  Of course, you could also define a version of `n1` that is specialized to `X`, but this would defeat the purpose of making `A` polymorphic.

Comment: The problem is that I can't pre-define Anat here, for example, if m1 : (A B) -> B, what shall I do?

Comment: Would it be OK for you to use type classes to fake coercions? You could define a type class `IsB T := toB : T -> B` and define a wrapper around `m1` that supposes an argument that implements this type class: `m1' x := m1 (toB x)`.  The problem is that this "coercion" won't be applied automatically in every function; you would need an overloaded version of each function that you expect to work with this coercion.

Comment: I might need some time to understand what you are saying. Anyway, thanks for your answer.